# Trying to add *double and double in a function

Tags: c

So I'm making a program to calculate a bank statement(school lab), this function that I'm making is to calculate in checks that have been withdrawn from the account as well as deposits.

Here is my main (that i have to use)

```
int main(void)
{
    char code;
    double amount, service, balance;
    double amtCheck, amtDeposit, openBalance, closeBalance;
    int numCheck, numDeposit;

    if (!(fpIn = fopen("account.txt", "r"))) {
        printf("account.txt could not be opened for input.");
        exit (1);
    }
    if (!(fpOut = fopen("csis.txt", "w"))) {
        printf("csis.txt could not be opened for output.");
        exit (1);
    }

    amount = 0.0;
    service = 0.0;
    balance = 0.0;
    amtCheck = 0.0;
    amtDeposit = 0.0;
    openBalance = 0.0;
    closeBalance = 0.0;
    numCheck = 0.0;
    numDeposit = 0.0;

    outputHeaders();

    while (!feof(fpIn)){
        fscanf(fpIn, "%c %lf\n", &code, &amount);
        if (code == 'I') {
            initialBalance(amount, &balance, &service, &openBalance);
        }
        else if (code == 'D'){
            deposit(amount, &balance, &service, &numDeposit, &amtDeposit);
        }
        else
        {
            check(amount, &balance, &service, &numCheck, &amtCheck);
        }
    }

    closeBalance = balance - service;
    outputSummary(numDeposit, amtDeposit, numCheck, amtCheck, openBalance,  service, closeBalance);
    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);
    return 0;

}
```

Here are my functions (that i have to use)

```
void check(double amount, double *balance, double *service, int *numCheck, double *amtCheck)
{
    ++*numCheck;
    service = numCheck * 0.06;
    amtCheck += amount;
    balance -= amtCheck;
}
```

the service is for service charge and is $0.06 per check deposited.
the numCheck is for the number of checks withdrawn.
the amtCheck is for the amount of $ withdrawn in checks.
the balance is the total($) of all withdraws at the end of the month.

in the function (void check) I'm trying to assign the product of numCheck * 0.06 (service = numCheck * 0.06) to service and for some reason it doesnt allow me. as well as trying to assign the the value of amtCheck + amount to amtCheck(amtCheck += amount) and it also doesnt allow me. What is the correct way of doing this?

(i have other functions to calculate the the deposits as well, but also having the same problem)

Comment: `but also having the same problem` <sigh> "What is the problem?"

Comment: service = numDeposit * 0.03;
 amtDeposit += amount; those dont work!

Comment: is says that the expression must have an arithmetic type for  service = numDeposit * 0.03; and for the amtDeposit += amount; it says it needs to have an integral type

Comment: Edit your question, don't put the key parts in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference your pointers when using their values or assigning values to them.
For example:

```
*service = (*numCheck)*0.06;
```